# selecting only two employees from every department

Tags: db2

Can you let me know how to select only two employees from every department? The table has deptname, ssn, name . I am doing a sampling and I need only two ssns for every department name. Can someone help?

Comment: please provide a table definition, data sample and preferred result output.

Comment: `select top 2 * from employee a inner join department b on a.ssn=b.ssn order by a.name`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with an "[OLAP expression](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzolapexp.htm)" row_number()

```
  with e as
  ( select deptname, ssn, empname,
           row_number() over (partition by dptname  order by empname) as pick
      from employees
  )
  select deptname, ssn, empname
    from e
    where pick < 3
    order by deptname, ssn
```

This example will give you the two employees with the lowest order names, because that is what is specified in the `row_number() (order by)` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from   t t1
where (
  select  count(*) 
  from t t2
  where 
    t2.deptname = t1.deptname 
    and 
    t2.ssn <= t1.ssn) <= 2 
order by deptname, ssn,name;
```

The above will give "smallest" two ssn.

> If you want top 2, change to t2.ssn >= t1.ssn

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45905/2)

**The data:**

[image: the data]

**The result from query:**

[image: the result from query]

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from 
  ( select rank() over (partition by dptname  order by empname) as count , *
    from employees
  )
  where count<=2 
  order by deptname, ssn,name;
```